# <css> cursor:pointer disappears

Tags: javascript, html, css

I ran into a strange issue related to the movement between elements that have cursor:pointer.

To recreate simply move your mouse up and down quickly between items.
To reset your cursor back to "pointer" simply move away from the viewport and the pointer is back.

Here is a screengrab.
Tested on various browsers, local environment, etc. Same deal on all.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eaEc.jpg

Here you can even see this issue from the snippet preview.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OXDf.jpg

Help will be appreciated.

```css
li {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 150px;
    line-height: .9;
  }

  span {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  span:hover {
    will-change: transform;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform 1s, color .2s;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: scale(1.2);
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>One</span></li>
  <li><span>Two</span></li>
  <li><span>Three</span></li>
  <li><span>Four</span></li>
  <li><span>Five</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce it using Chrome `88.0.4324.150` on a Mac. Also you're not closing the first `span` tag.

Comment: I what browser? Not reproducible in Chrome 88 on Win10

Comment: no need to put cursor:pointer on span:hover, because it's already on the li. Perhaps remove it from both and just add it to the span

Comment: Chrome 88.0.4324.152 here, Firefox 86.0b6 (64-bit) I can reproduce it 100% on any client, try scrolling just a bit if it isn't reproducing the combination kills it. You just have to move quickly between items for a couple of seconds as shown in the clip. Can even reproduce it here in the snippet preview. As a sanity check, moving this quickly is pretty absurd to begin with. This is just for illustration purposes, on an actual site it happens just when you scroll and hover over the items.

Comment: I can fix it with js and animationFrame but setting the cursor every tick is not really my cup of tea.

Comment: Just curious why are you setting `cursor:pointer` on `hover` and not simply to `span`? Can you check if it solves your issue. I'm not able to reproduce this on Chrome & FF.

Comment: I also cant repro with latest stable chrome. Based on your gif, looks like something else but browser interfered with your cursor behavior. Perhaps addons? Btw, are you using a touchpad?

Comment: No, I am not. But it will be great if you can't reproduce and it is indeed a local issue. Tried on a touchpad, cant reproduce there as well.